# Cisco 877 VPN: PPTP encryption not working

Tags: vpn, cisco, encryption, pptp

A followup to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/130550/cisco-877-as-a-vpn-server).

I have a Cisco 877 ADSL router configured (at last!) to act as a VPN server; it supports both PPTP and L2TP VPNs, and I can successfully connect to it from Windows computers using the built-in VPN software.

There is only one problem: when using a PPTP VPN, encryption doesn't work. If I configure the client to require encryption (default setting), the connection fails with an error about the remote endpoint not supporting it. If I remove the encryption requirement, the connection succeeds. I've also tried tweaking the encryption settings (40/128 bits), but this didn't work either.

This is the relevant part of the router's configuration; the complete config is available in the question I linked above.

```
vpdn enable
vpdn-group VPN_Clients
 accept-dialin
  protocol any
  virtual-template 1

ip local pool VPN_Pool 192.168.42.250 192.168.42.254

interface Virtual-Template1
 ip unnumbered Vlan1
 ip nat inside
 peer default ip address pool VPN_Pool
 ppp encrypt mppe auto required
 ppp authentication ms-chap-v2 ms-chap chap
```

The router's IOS version is 15, and it fully supports encryption.

The strangest thing is, encryption is actually *required* in the router config; but not only the router doesn't seem to offer it... it also accepts unencrypted connections, which it shouldn't. It's like the `ppp encrypt mppe auto required` command is completely ignored.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure really, perhaps there is a separation here between the encryption of authentication and encryption of the data transmission.

Comment: That command (according to the documentation) has the exact purpose of turning on **data** encryption.

Comment: I know that PPTP is built upon GRE tunnels, I'll check with someone on why you're seeing what you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug.

I updated the router's IOS from version 15.0(1) to 15.1(3) and now the problem is gone.

Comment: Apologies for topping and old topic, but I've followed this thread, and the thread it followed on from, with interest. We're in exactly the same position - need to configure a Cisco 877 router as a VPN server. However, the instructions in the first thread are to setup a PPTP VPN, which I now believe are insecure. If this is the case what are you using instead?

Comment: The accepted answer in the first thread enables both PPTP and L2TP.